# Problems with basename in a loop

Tags: shell, for-loop

I am new at shell script programming and I'm trying to execute a software that reads a text and perform it's POS tagging. It requires an input and an output, as can be seen in the execute example:

```
$ cat input.txt | /path/to/tagger/run-Tagger.sh > output.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is to execute this line not only for a text, but a set of texts in an specific folder, and return the output files with the same name as the input files. So, I tried to do this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/"
program="/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/LX-Tagger/POSTagger/Tagger/run-Tagger.sh"

for arqin in '/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/*'
do
out=$(basename $arqin)
output=$path$out
cat $arqin | $program > $output
done
```

I tried it with only one file and it works, but when I try with more than one, I get this error:

```
basename: extra operand ‘/home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/3’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.

./scriptLXTagger.sh: 12: ./scriptLXTagger.sh: cannot create /home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/: Is a directory
```

Any insights on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of `$arqin` before the call to `basename`? And you should probably quote your variables, e.g: `$(basename "$arqin")`

Answer (score 4):

You don't want quotes around the pattern, and quote your variables:

```
for arqin in /home/rafaeldaddio/Documents/teste/*
do
    out=$(basename "$arqin")
    output=$path$out
    "$program" <"$arqin" >"$output"
done
```